# Regular expression to match string and then specific numbers

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regular expression for a string entry with two components:

BV001ID is going to be the first part of the string, and it must always begin with this.

Then there will be a three digit number. The first digit must be either 0, 2, or 9. The following two digits can be any number.

So for example, a valid response can be BV001ID041. A valid response could not be BV001ID301 or BV001010.

This seems to be working for the three digit number: `[0,2,9]\d\d`

But I'm not sure how to add the string in front.

Comment: Just put the text as literal and no commas in the character class: `BV001ID[029]\d\d`

Comment: Oh wow thanks @trincot! That was simple. How do I mark you as having answered my question?

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just prefix literal characters into your regular expression. You should however remove the commas from the character class, as otherwise you actually allow a comma. Every single character in a character class represents a possible match, so only list those, like `[029]`

So do:

```
BV001ID[029]\d\d
```

Answer (score -1):

Longhand version I came up with:

```
^BV001ID[0,2,9][0-9][0-9]
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try this \BV001ID[0,2,9]\d\d